# What is the proper method of using sql join with more than two tables?

Tags: sql, database

I have a tricky (to me, at least) challenge involving a query on 3 different tables to find the:

Study_ID, Study_Name, Price, Sdate on all students
in grade.freshman (grade=freshman)

I started trying to piece it together, but I quickly became lost in the complexity. I feel like you need to join, but I can't puzzle it out.

This is as far as I got before getting lost.

```
SELECT Study_ID, Study_Name, Price, Sdate
     FROM Receives
          INNER JOIN Study ON Study_ID, Study_Name
          INNER JOIN Student ON Grade='freshmen';
```

Unfortunately, that is it. Here are the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
     S_ID char(6), 
     Name varchar(20), 
     Grade varchar(20), 
     Age integer, 
     PRIMARY KEY(S_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Study(
     Study_ID varchar(6), 
     Study_Name varchar(20), 
     Label varchar(15), 
     PRIMARY KEY (Study_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Receives(
     S_ID char(6), 
     Study_ID char(6), 
     Sdate date, 
     Price decimal(5,2), 
     PRIMARY KEY(S_ID, Study_ID), 
     FOREIGN KEY(Study_ID)  
     REFERENCES Study(Study_ID)
);
```

Comment: Note that `Student.Grade = "freshman"` is conceptually a selection/filter condition, rather than a join condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches: consider how the tables are related to each other, and consider the columns/foreign keys in the tables.

The Student and Study tables aren't directly related, but the Receives table is the relationship between the two (it's sometimes called an [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), junction, link or composite table, among other terms), so you can join Student and Study through Receives.

From the column/foreign key approach, the Receives table has columns that reference the Student and Study tables, so it can be used to join those tables (the definition of `Receives` is missing the `Student(S_ID)` foreign key, which becomes noticeable when you consider how the tables are related).

In SQL, it would look something like:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM Receives
    INNER JOIN Study ON ...
    INNER JOIN Student ON ...
```

The order of tables in the JOIN clauses is a matter of style; here, I give the joining table first. More typically, I list them as they are joined (which reads more like natural language). For example, `Student ⋈ Receives ⋈ Study` ("A student Receives study"), or (in SQL):

```
Student
  JOIN Receives ON ...
  JOIN Study ON ...
```

Comment: I changed my original attempt to reflect your help. Maybe something like that? Sorry, I'm not able to test it where I'm at right now.

Comment: @lindabaldwell: it's better not to change the original question, as it creates a new question and can invalidate answers. If you want clarifications in an answer, you can always ask in the comments.